# Ubuntu 18.04 laptop outputs only 4k 30hz to my TV. How to get 60hz?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I can't set 4k 60hz for my TV. I have Ubuntu 18.04 OS, NVIDIA MX250 GPU, a version 2.1 HDMI and a TV with which I got 4k 60 Hz running with my other laptop with Windows OS.

`xrandr` listed only 30 Hz for 4k. I tried manually adding 4k 60 Hz mode through `xrandr`.

I am [attaching NVIDIA bug report output file](https://paste.ee/p/QnAeT).

Also the `lshw -c video` output:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:141 memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

*-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:143 memory:93000000-93ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:5000(size=128)
```

Could you people help me figure this out and get 4k 60 Hz?

Comment: what's the specs of the other laptop running Windows? also I think you forgot to attach the Nvidia bug report.

Comment: Did you use the same HDMI cable for both laptops and in the same HDMI input on the TV? (Sometimes some TVs have different spec HDMI ports, e.g. sometimes not all are the same spec HDMI). Also I would edit your question with the results of `xrandr` when the TV is connected.

Comment: Windows 10 laptop has 960m GPU. Thanks for reminding btw. Yes I used the same cable with every HDMI slot on TV.

Comment: As well as the output from `xrandr` I would also add your output from `lshw -c video` to show all graphics adaptors.

Comment: @Fsrn maybe just the difference between the GPUs causes this? as a test, try booting an Ubuntu Live USB on the Windows laptop and try to output 4k 60Hz video from there. that would tell us if it's the Ubuntu laptop graphics card's specs not being enough.

Comment: As far as i researched even the intel graphics can handle multiple 4k displays. So, I would say that MX250 can at least run as good as intel gpu.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much but I went through the nvidia log file. It is possible that the HDMI connection for my laptop somehow can support only up to 30hz for 4k. Can anyone confirm?